# What does the double colon ('::') mean in Actionscript 3 / Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm tasked with updating a Flex project created by an outside contractor and in the Actionscript is the following chunk:

```
CONFIG::FLASH_10_1
{
    //Some code here
}
```

I've never seen this type of structure before and I'm having a heck of a time trying to search for it on Google - I've found what it means in just about every programming language except AS3.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I should probably add that currently the project is throwing an error at this line that reads: "1120: Access of undefined property FLASH_10_1"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this relates to the [conditional compilation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html) features of the Flex compiler.

So, if you add a compiler argument, like this:

```
-define=CONFIG::FLASH_10_1
```

I bet that error will go away.

Comment: That was it exactly!  Thanks a ton Flextras for the answer and the informative link.  I actually ended up adding -define=CONFIG:FLASH_10_1,true to specify that this was a 10.1 requirement.

Comment: Glad to help!  Just be clear, if you want your app to target a specific version of the Flash Player, I do not believe conditional compilation will do it.  You'll want to use the target-player command line argument. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not the same context, to answer the question of what double colon "::" means in AS3...

It is a namespace accessor.

For example, the AS3 `Vector.<T>` type actually has a runtime type name of `__AS3__.vec::Vector.<T>`, where `__AS3__.vec` is the custom namespace. You can also use custom namespaces for members and access them on objects in AS3 using the syntax `object.custom_namespace::membername`. `public` and `private` are built in namespaces, so technically you could access public members like `object.public::membername`, as in:

```
var a:Array = [0,1];
trace(a.public::length); //prints 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a flex / AS3 guru - this thread talks about the '::' being used as a "Namespace accessor":

[Thread on Actionscript FAQs](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=195916)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately that applies to e4x and XML, not the construct I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry - wish it was a bit more helpful. Thought I would throw a search to see if I could come up with anything - but hopefully Flextras solved your problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this applies to AS3 as well. For example, the AS3 `Vector.<T>` type actually has a runtime type name of `__AS3__.vec::Vector.<T>`, where `__AS3__.vec` is the custom namespace. You can also use custom namespaces for members and access them on objects in AS3 using the syntax `object.custom_namespace::membername`. `public` and `private` are built in namespaces, so technically you could access public members like this `object.public::membername`, as in `var a:Array = [0,1]; trace(a.public::length); //prints 2`